# How do I set-up reporting from my Workflow in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 and have created a workflow for IT requests. I would like to set-up automated reports that are exported and sent to the team on a weekly basis to track the status of items. Can someone point me in the right direction to start this in 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Two points actually,

1. You should let your workflow be a workflow. A workflow is supposed to automate a specific business process and I wouldn't try to make it do two different things, just for the sake of cleanliness.
2. To get the reports every week, the simplest possible approach would be to create a console application, running every week (say, inside the task scheduler) and collecting all the data, and (A) either uploading to some reports library in your site (which has a workflow on ItemAdded to trigger emails), or (B) directly mailing them to your team. The good thing about approach (A) is that you get the whole history of reports stored on SharePoint whenever you might need.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Nisarg. I think I'm not clear on what I'm trying to accomplish. I guess what I want is a report to show the status of a list that has a Worfklow on it. For instance, an IT ticketing system that has different stages: Active, Resolved, Completed. I'd like an Excel spreadsheet generated to show how many of each and who is assigned to each ticket. Can you point me in a direction to generate an Excel workbook from a list?

Comment: You could begin by learning about SharePoint's Client Side Object Model -  called CSOM. It will let you write a .net code to get your list items and their column values. Next you have to export the data into excel. Now although there are many libraries, as a beginner you could start with EPPlus.